# Unable to use multiple KMS keys in AvroParquetWriter with Hadoop configuration for SSE

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet, amazon-kms

Using a Java application that runs on an AWS EC2 instance (not hadoop cluster) I use the parquet-hadoop/avro library to create AvroParquetWriters to generate parquet files and then write those files to a bucket in S3. I create multiple AvroParquetWriters with different configurations that specify different KMS keys to use for encryption but all files created use the same kms key for encryption (it uses the key that was first used in a configuration).

Here is how I am creating the `Configuration`s and `Writer`s:

```
Configuration conf1 = new Configuration();

conf1.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption.key", awsKmsId1);
conf1.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "SSE-KMS");
conf1.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true");
conf1.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", s3Endpoint);


Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();

conf2.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption.key", awsKmsId2);
conf2.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "SSE-KMS");
conf2.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true");
conf2.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", s3Endpoint);



ParquetWriter<GenericRecord> writer1 = AvroParquetWriter.<GenericRecord>builder(path)
                    .withSchema(parquetSchema)
                    .withConf(conf1)
                    .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.CREATE)
                    .build();

ParquetWriter<GenericRecord> writer2 = AvroParquetWriter.<GenericRecord>builder(path)
                    .withSchema(parquetSchema)
                    .withConf(conf2)
                    .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.CREATE)
                    .build();
```

`writer1` and `writer2` create different files but both are encrypted with the `awsKmsId1` key even though I specify different ones.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem! This issue was being caused by the `FileSystem` cache in hadoop-common (3.3.0). It doesn't use the `Configuration` object when building the cache keys so when it tries to get the `FileSystem` from the cache, it returns the old `FileSystem` because the URI scheme is the same. I fixed this by disabling the cache with `conf.set("fs.s3a.impl.disable.cache", "true");`.
This issue can be seen in this Apache Jira [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8490)